# Vue 3: Emit event from parent to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Now I need to emit event from parent to child component. I see in vue version 3 `$on`, `$off` and `$once` instance methods are removed. Application instances no longer implement the event emitter interface.

How now I can emit events from parent component and listen from child component in vue version 3?

Comment: Can you not use props? A reactive property passed down as prop from parent to child will automatically allow you to do things on the child.

Comment: @AliGajani I said about like this actions in vue 3 https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html

Comment: Parent child communication via props is a strategy and I don't think anything in that regard changes between Vue 2 and Vue 3. If you want to emit an event from parent to child, props is the way to go. Since the property passed into the prop via parent will be either data() or computed(), it will be reactive, allowing you to watch and do things on the child. Just my two cents.

Comment: how were you using those methods in vue 2 to emit events from parent into child component? those seem to be emitting events on a globally accessible “bus” hence it is not strictly parent -> child communication. You can use any global event emitter for that purpose?

Answer (score 17):

You can access to child methods by using `Refs`

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html

```vue
<!-- Parent -->
<template>
    <ChildComponent ref="childComponentRef" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent.vue'

export default { 
  setup( ) {
    const childComponentRef = ref()
    childComponentRef.value.expandAll();

    return { childComponentRef }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Child -->
<script>
export default {
    setup() {
        const expandAll= () => {
            //logic...
        }

        return { expandAll}
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If using `<script setup>` please refer to [refs on components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component). You must expose the function you wish to call from the parent using `defineExpose({})`

Answer (score 6):

You would not listen from the child component for parent events, you would instead pass a prop down to the child and if the child component needs to update the data you would emit an event from child to parent to update the state.

Read only life cycle:
Parent > Prop > Child

Read/Update life cycle:
Parent > Prop > Child > Emit > Parent > Update > Child Updates

Comment: How about "expandAll", for example? I have parent with button and datatable child with expandable rows. Each child row has a grandchild datatable again with expandable rows. I want to click the button and expand or collapse all child and all grandchildren datatable rows. If I just pass a flag in props it would keep the rows expanded/collapsed and not allow user to change state of any single row...?

Comment: And what about a global handler for catching `ctrl`+`v`. I want to emit the content of the clipboard to an upload component *when* there is one on the page.

Comment: What if I want to trigger a function inside the child? Not like "do this until the prop is false" but "do this exactly once and do it again if it is being triggered again".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots).

For example, in the parent to the "slotted" component:

`Parent.vue`:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useToggle } from '@/composables'

const props = defineProps({
  show: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  }
})

const { isOpen, close, open, toggle } = useToggle(props.show)
</script>

<template>
  <slot
    :on-open="open"
    :on-close="close"
    :on-toggle="toggle"
  />
</template>
```

*Where we have used a basic toggle composable.

In the `Grandparent.vue` component, we can then scope some of the method trigger events to the `Child.vue` component of the parent as follows:

`GrandParent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <Parent>
    <template #default="{ onToggle }">
      <Child 
        @toggle="onToggle" 
      />
    </template>
  </Parent>
</template>
```

*Change `#default` to whatever your slot name is called, or leave as default if no name.

And then in the Child.vue component, we make sure to emit the event up:

`Child.vue`:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'toggle'): void
}>()

const toggle = () => {
  emit('toggle')
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle Event</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were like me calling some event on `this.$root.$on(...)` and `this.$root.$emit(...)` in Vue2 from any parent/child to any child/parent for somehow keep your code cleaner rather then using bunch of emits and props respectively and have your code blows up..

from Vue3 doc, event bus pattern can be replaced by using an external library implementing the event emitter interface.
use a library that implement a pub-sub pattern or write it.
[vue3 event description](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#event-bus)

Now if you're using the Option-API (like vue 2) y need to import that event file then using it right a way in any component.

if you are using the `<script setup>` you need add extra step in order to you that event library heres the code.

here's a basic example of pub-sub javascript pattern, don't forget to add the off method and call it on `beforeUnmounted`(v3), `beforeDestroy`(v2)   to not have multiple function execution for each mounted call )

```
    //event.js
    
class Event{
        constructor(){
            this.events = {};
        }
    
        on(eventName, fn) {
            this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
            this.events[eventName].push(fn);
        }
        emit = (eventName, data)=> (this.events[eventName]) ? this.events[eventName].forEach( fn => fn(data)) : '' ;  
    }
    
    export default new Event();
```

if you're doing vue2 like syntax Option-API:
//in vue component

```
import event from './event';
//mounted or any methods
even.on('GG', data=> console.log(`GG Event received ${data}`))
```

//obviously you have to emit that from another component
//...

```
import event from './event';
//on mounted or methods click or...
even.emit('GG', {msg:"Vue3 is super Cool"});
```

if you're using the `<script setup>` which means all variables and methods are exposed by default to the template.

```
//in main.js
import event from './event.js';
//..
app.config.globalProperties.$event = event;
//..

//note if you have an error make sure that you split the the app chaining, like this :

let app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$event = event;
app.mount('#app');
```

//add a file called useEvent.js

```
// useEvent.js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
export default  useEvent => getCurrentInstance().appContext.app.config.globalProperties.$event;
```

//using it in a `<script setup>`

```
import useEvent from '@/useEvent'
const event    =  useEvent();
event.emit('GG');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with a way of emitting an event from a parent to a child component. Be aware as this is a very ugly workaround !!

```
//child

setup(){
  // get the current instance
  const instance = getCurrentInstance();

  // function to find the parent instance
  const getParentComponent = (name: string) => {
    let component = null;
    if (instance) {
      let parent = instance.parent;
      while (parent && !component) {
        if (parent.type.name === name) {
          component = parent;
        }
        parent = parent.parent;
      }
      return component;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

  // listener that will be called from within the parent component
  const eventFunction = () => {
    console.log('event fired !!')
  }
      
  onMounted(() => {
    const $parent = getParentComponent('ParentComponentName');

    // register the current instance to the parent component
    if($parent && $parent.props && $parent.props.childInstances){
      ($parent.props.childInstances as any[]).push(instance)
    }
  })

  return {
    eventFunction
  }
}
```

```
//parent

name: 'ParentComponentName',
props: {
  childInstances: {
    type: Array as PropType<any[]>,
    required: false, 
    default: () => [] as any[]
  }
},
setup(props){
  const emitChildComponentEvent = (event: string) => {
    if(props.childInstances.length > 0){
      props.childInstances.forEach((component: any) => {
        if(typeof component.proxy[event] === 'function'){
          component.proxy[event]()
        }
      })
    }
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    emitChildComponentEvent('eventFunction');
  })
}
```